# How can I add One-Tap Sign In with Google with Firebase Authentication

Tags: javascript, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I would like to add **Google One-Tap Sign In** to my website, however I don't know how to connect it to my Firebase authentication service.

According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/display-google-one-tap) I should add an HTML tag containing a `data-client_id`, but where can I find that Client ID in the Firebase Authentication configuration?

The client ID that I'm using ends up with: `****.apps.googleusercontent.com`, and the `data-login_uri` that I'm using is `https://<MY_APP>.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/handler`. Yet, that doesn't work.

After clicking on my Google account I get redirected to another page with the message: Unable to process request due to missing initial state. This may happen if browser sessionStorage is inaccessible or accidentally cleared. Some specific scenarios are - 1) Using IDP-Initiated SAML SSO. 2) Using signInWithRedirect in a storage-partitioned browser environment.

[image: Sign In One-Time Button]

[image: Error after Sign-In]

Code Snippet:

```html
<div
  id="g_id_onload"
  data-client_id="*.apps.googleusercontent.com"
  data-context="signin"
  data-nonce=""
  data-login_uri="https://my-app.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/handler"
  data-itp_support="true"
>
```

Comment: See here for more details (https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/reference/html-reference#data-client_id)

Answer (score 0):

This [page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/google-signin#expandable-2) should provide you some pointers on integrating Sign in with Google SDK with Firebase. Though it points to the Sign in with Google button instead of One Tap, the same principle applies.

Comment: Is it necessary to create a custom `_/auth/handler` instead of using the one already provided by Firebase?